# Check a checkbox on link click using value from data-attribute (possible on change clash?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following jQuery code which has a link and a checkbox.

When the edit link is clicked it gets the data attribute on the link and checks the checkbox accordingly.

I also need the functionality to change the value of the checkbox if it is checked or unchecked by the user. So on change it's value gets amended to 1 or 0.

**Issue**

if I uncheck the box, the value becomes 0 as expected but then if I click the link again the checkbox remains unchecked.

**How To Replicate**

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdpvnt5h/1/)

1. Click the link
2. Uncheck the checkbox
3. Click the link again

I am expecting the checkbox to be checked as per the `if( changecheckboxvalto == 1 )` condition.

**Code**

```
$('body').on('click', '#edit', function() {

  // Get the change checkbox val

  changecheckboxvalto = $(this).attr('data-changecheckboxvalto');
  console.log('changecheckboxvalto = ' + changecheckboxvalto);

  if( changecheckboxvalto == 1 ) {

    $('#myinput').val(1).attr('checked', true);

  } else {

    $('#myinput').val(0).attr('checked', false);

  }

  // click checkbox makes chekbox value change to 1 or 0

  $('#myinput').change(function() {
    console.log('change happened');
    if( $(this).val() == 0 ) {
      $(this).val(1).attr('checked', true);
      console.log('change condition 1');
    } else {
      $(this).val(0).attr('checked', false);
      console.log('change condition 2');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi, you probably need to carefully read this http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would be it:

```
if( changecheckboxvalto == 1 ) {

    $('#myinput').val(1).attr('checked', true);

} else {

    $('#myinput').val(0).attr('checked', false);

}
```

When `changecheckboxvalto == 1`, it sets the value to `1`. Otherwise, it is set to `0`. The `.val(0)` part will never activate as it is always `1`. Also, the attribute is set on `#edit`, but you are changing it on `#myinput`. Set to this:

```
if( changecheckboxvalto == 1 ) {

    $('#edit').attr('data-changecheckboxvalto', 0);
    $('#myinput').attr('checked', true);

} else {

    $('#edit').attr('data-changecheckboxvalto', 1);
    $('#myinput').attr('checked', false);

}
```

Comment: Well, the checkbox gets its value changed to 0 upon unchecking. If I click the link after this I would expect changecheckboxvalto to still be 1 and therefore the checkbox gets checked, but it doesn't. So I don't see how that helps...? The else condition there is just to test if I manually change the data-attribute to 0 - the console log even states it is 1.

Comment: Hold on...found a solution!

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge I updated it with the correct solution.

Comment: The data-changecheckboxvalto is always 1, it doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge If it's always 1, why would it need to exist? Why not just replace it with `1 == 1`?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want the link to only push the checkbox one way and not the other** (always make it true, or always make it false), then here is a solution :

```
// Get the link
var link = $('#edit');

// Get the checkbox
var checkbox = $('#myinput');


// Add an onclick to the link

link.on('click', function () {

    // Get the value of the link attribute 'data-changecheckboxvalto'
    var pushedValue = link.attr('data-changecheckboxvalto');

    // Change the attribute checked accordingly
    checkbox.prop('checked', pushedValue);
    // NB : for jQuery < 1.6, use "checkbox.attr('checked', pushedValue);"

});
```

Same thing in pure JS

```
// Get the link
var link = document.querySelector('#edit');

// Get the checkbox
var checkbox = document.querySelector('#myinput');


// Add an onclick to the link

link.onclick = function () {

    // Get the value of changecheckboxvalto
    var pushedValue = link.dataset.changecheckboxvalto;

    // Change the value of the checkbox checked attribute
    checkbox.checked = pushedValue;

};
```

**If on the other hand** you are trying to make the link and the checkbox 'twins', then you can get rid of `data-changecheckboxvalto` and do one of the following :

Here is a solution using jQuery

```
// Get the link
var link = $('#edit');

// Get the checkbox
var checkbox = $('#myinput');


// Add an onclick to the link

link.on('click', function () {

    // Get the value of the checkbox attribute 'checked'
    var checkboxState = checkbox.prop('checked');
    // NB : for jQuery < 1.6, use "checkbox.attr('checked');"

    // Inverse the value of the attribute checked
    checkbox.prop('checked', !checkboxState);
    // NB : for jQuery < 1.6, use "checkbox.attr('checked', !checkboxState);"

});
```

Same thing in pure JS

```
// Get the link
var link = document.querySelector('#edit');

// Get the checkbox
var checkbox = document.querySelector('#myinput');


// Add an onclick to the link

link.onclick = function () {

    // Inverse the value of the attribute checked
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;

}
```

Let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the 'prop' function .

change `$('#myinput').val(1).attr('checked', true);` to `$('#myinput').val(1).prop('checked', true);` and `$('#myinput').val(0).attr('checked', false);` to `$('#myinput').val(0).prop('checked', false);`